# The scroll is not working on UITableView when it has preloaded data

Tags: ios

I have an archive screen, where I am trying to display previous saved data inside an UITableView, I am doing this

```
 self.previousValues = [arrLogs mutableCopy];
 [self.listTableView reloadData];
```

the data is being updated inside the UITableView but the scroll is not working
I have tried a bunch of solutions but I am not getting it working

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue 
      `self.previousValues = [arrLogs mutableCopy];
    [self.logsTableView layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.listTableView reloadData];`

I just included [self.logsTableView layoutIfNeeded]; before [self.listTableView reloadData];